# NEST : Issue in getting data from search response (ISearchResponse) in ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-aggregation

I wrote a C# code using NEST, which makes search queries to my ES database. I can see these queries succeed and give a json response body through Postman. I want to use these responses in my code. For example,

`ISearchResponse<class> myquery = client.Search<class>(...)`
(some successful api call)

The response body is something like:

```
{
  "took": 5,
  ...
  ...
  "hits": {
    "max_score": 1.2,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "sample",
        ...
        "_source": {
          "name": "generic name",
          "profession": "lawyer",
          ...
        }
      }
    ]
  }
    "aggs" : {
       ...
    }
}
```

I can get the "took" value here by doing `myquery.Took`. Similarly I can see the definition of `ISearchResponse<>` contains data members for `MaxScore`, `TimedOut` etc.

My question is, In the same way if I want to get the value of, say the `name` field or some bucket in `aggr`, to use in my code. How can I do this? Please Help.

Note : 
The Documentation only explained how to handle error responses and I can see in the debugger that probably `.Documents` is storing this somehow, but I'm not able to retrieve the data  (or probably I can't understand how to). So please also explain how to get it from `.Documents` if that is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `"_source"` JSON object of each hit will be deserialized into the type `T` specified as the generic type parameter on `Search<T>`. In your example, `"_source"` will be deserialized into `class`, so simply define properties on `class` for the properties on `"_source"`. For example

```cs
public class MyDocument 
{
    [PropertyName(Name = "name")]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [PropertyName(Name = "profession")]
    public string Profession {get;set;}
}

var response = client.Search<MyDocument>();
```